# Incorrectly thinks files have been changed

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

I have created a new Visual Studio 2013 project out of files which were previously attached to a Visual Studio 2017 project. I have left the Git folder unchanged, but now Visual Studio 2013's Team Explorer thinks that every file has been changed, even if I "undo" every change.

How do I stop this? The files have not changed/moved, they're just being referenced by a new project.

If I do a compare with the old versions, it shows no changes.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an EOL issue.  Do you have a .gitattributes file in the repo that defines the handling of EOL in text files?

Comment: It only has a .gitignore.

Comment: Wouldn't undo deal with changing EOLs?

Comment: when your version control tells you the files differ, but a diff reveals nothing, its usually either EOL issues, or BOM issues (Byte Order Mark). At least in my experience